# Slicing in Pytorch gives a wrong answer

Tags: python, pytorch

When I run the following lines, I see the following result which I can't explain. I expected to see [1., 2.] as the answer to a*x[:,0] and indeed if I do the same thing in numpy, I get that answer but I don't know why pytorch gives me a different answer:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([[1,0],[1,1]]) 
>>> a = torch.tensor([1.,2.]) 
>>> a*x 
tensor([[1., 0.], [1., 2.]]) 
>>> a*x[:,0] 
tensor([1., nan])
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using version 1.2.0. Maybe it is somehow related to the data types. In version 1.2.0 you have to explicitly cast `x` into a float tensor (previously `long`). I had strange behaviour in similar cases before. So I think this is just some kind of bug. So it appears that you are using an older version and if you want to get rid of this issue updating your pytorch might help.

Answer (score 0):

confirming @blue-phoenox: tried out your example in 1.1 and 1.2. You'll get the following error:

`RuntimeError: expected backend CPU and dtype Float but got backend CPU and dtype Long`

additionally, careful when slicing to a 1d tensor as you'll go from shape `[2, 2]` to `[2]` instead of `[1, 2]` , which may or may not be desired.